# Meteor is crashing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am having an issue with Meteor and Jquery. I have add in both underscore.js and jquery yet I still get the follow error when I try and run the code. The server fails before it ever starts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a copy of the output window. I know I am missing something really simple. I can get other meteor apps to run.

```
=> Meteor server running on: localhost:3000/

.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:34
5
  }).run();
     ^
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at app/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js:4:4148
    at \.meteor\local\build\server\serve
r.js:306:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\rodgerse\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:79:11)
    at run (\.meteor\local\build\server\
server.js:239:7)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted

\.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:34
5
  }).run();
     ^
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at app/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js:4:4148
    at \.meteor\local\build\server\serve
r.js:306:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\rodgerse\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:79:11)
    at run (\.meteor\local\build\server\
server.js:239:7)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted

\.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:34
5
  }).run();
     ^
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at app/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js:4:4148
    at \.meteor\local\build\server\serve
r.js:306:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\rodgerse\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:79:11)
    at run (\.meteor\local\build\server\
server.js:239:7)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `jQuery` is available? It seems that jQuery UI doesn't have access to jQuery.

Comment: "I have add in both underscore.js and jquery" - jQuery and Underscore are included by default in Meteor, because Meteor's core uses both of them. You don't need to do anything to add them. Note that you can only use jQuery in client code, but you can use Underscore on both client and server code.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate through arrays on the server, you should use underscore's `._each` method. It comes with Meteor so there are no packages to install or anything like that.

So, instead of:

```
$.each(someArray, function (index, element) {
   //Some awesome logic
})
```

You can do:

```
_.each(someArray, function (element, index, list) {
    //Some awesome logic.
});
```

[Check this out](http://underscorejs.org/#each) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is only available on the client - not the server [[1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/jquery/package.js#L9)]. So, because it has a dependency on jQuery, your file will only work on the client. You should put it in the `client` directory:

```
app/client/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js
```